# Rythm can't @import a template if invoked by a parent template

Tags: java, rythm

I have a set 4 template files, all with the `.rythm` extension, and all living in the same directory.  Let's call them "Main.rythm", "Child1.rythm", "Child2.rythm", and "Helper.rythm".  Additionally, I also set the `home.template.dir` to this directory before rendering Main.

In the Helper template, I just have a bunch of `@def`s that do some basic common formatting so that I don't have to call back to a my java class or clutter up the actual template with logic that doesn't need to be there.

Main looks something like this:

```
@args {
    String aString,
    MyClass bunchOfData,
    String anotherString
    @//...
}
@import("Helper")
There's some formatting here, using @aString
There's some formatting using an @def in Helper, like @foo(anotherString)

@Child1(bunchOfData)

@Child2(bunchOfData)
```

And Child1 and Child2 are similar to each other and look something like this:

```
@args MyClass bunchOfData
@import("Helper")
@{
    //Some preformatting stuff here
}
Make a lot of method calls on @bunchOfData, some of which will also use an @def or two in Helper
```

My problem is that I'm getting an error in Child1 on the `@import("Helper")` line:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.rythmengine.exception.CompileException: Syntax error on token "import", delete this token

Template: /path/to/templates/Child1.rythm
```

I've tried commenting out the `@import`, but then I can't really call those `@def`s, and get errors from Rythm that "Helper cannot be resolved" when I use `@Helper.foo(bunchOfData.getSomething())`.

What is it that I need to do in order to get access to these `@def`s in Helper from Child1 and Child2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `@import`, you should be using `@include` instead.  `@import` is just like the `import` directive in java, adding a package for this template to refer to.  `@include` is for adding additional templates that you can refer to throughout this template.

Comment: Correct, for more information about template reuse, please checkout out http://rythmengine.org/doc/template_guide.md#reuse-methods-summary